# Disable 'Deploy' button for inbound changeset

Tags: deployment, change-set

Is there any way to disable the 'Deploy' button for inbound changesets? As per my requirement, certain profile users should not have permission to deploy inbound changeset in production, so I wanted to see if I can only disable the 'Deploy' button. I tried disabling Deploy inbound changeset from system permission, but then users won't be able to find inbound changesets from Setup so this permission did not work for me. If there are any other options available, then please let me know.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That permission is it. Either users can see and deploy the change sets, or not.